# PowerShell Error Copying a folder to remote server

Tags: powershell, copy-item

am trying for a long time to copy the following folder to remote server but unfortunately giving always error.
I try alot of ways :((((

I really need a help

**The code:**

```
$ServerLists = Get-Content -Path "c:\scripts\serverslist.txt"
$NewRFCName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter New RFC Name'
 foreach ($server in $ServerLists)
        {
           $from =  "C:\Releases\" + $NewRFCName
           $exchange = New-PSSession -ComputerName $server -Credential $Credential
          #    #######Copy the new pakage to Website folder : #######
          Write-Host "server :$server \\ Copying the new pakgae to Website folder "
          Invoke-Command -Session $exchange -ScriptBlock {Copy-Item $from  C:\site -Recurse}
        }
```

**The Error:**

Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scriptblock passed to `Invoke-Command` will be executed *on the remote machine*, where the `$from` variable doesn't exist.

You can force PowerShell to copy it's value to the remote session by specifying the `using:` prefix:

```
$ServerLists = Get-Content -Path "c:\scripts\serverslist.txt"
$NewRFCName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter New RFC Name'

foreach ($server in $ServerLists) {
    $from = "C:\Releases\" + $NewRFCName
    $exchange = New-PSSession -ComputerName $server -Credential $Credential
    #    #######Copy the new pakage to Website folder : #######
    Write-Host "server :$server \\ Copying the new pakgae to Website folder "
    Invoke-Command -Session $exchange -ScriptBlock { Copy-Item $using:from  C:\site -Recurse }
}
```

Or by explicitly passing it as an argument to the remote session:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $exchange -ScriptBlock { param([string]$Path) Copy-Item $Path C:\site -Recurse } -ArgumentList $from
```